# How to: REST API that passes and array of key/value pairs

Tags: arrays, node.js, rest

I am looking for guidance in implementing a REST API that passes and array of key/value pairs.

Specifically my data looks like:

```
[{0:1},{1:5},{7:2}...]
```

the 'key' is an index into a 60 element array.
The value is represents one of several enumerated values.
The array is stored in the database but maintained by the client.
The number of array entries (array length) is known at run time (ie. must be variable).

What is the best way to represent this in the uri?
And, how would the server decode that parameter(s)?

This would be implemented via a GET and a PUT request.
Server is written in Node.js

Comment: Are you trying to send this data to the server or query this data from the server?  You may want to read [When to use PUT or POST](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/) if you're sending data to the server.  You would use a GET if you are querying data from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use json to send it across the network with this header application/x-www-form-urlencoded. That's where multipart/form-data comes in. With this method of transmitting name/value pairs.

In other words,for application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the body of the HTTP message sent to the server is essentially one giant query string -- name/value pairs are separated by the ampersand (&), and names are separated from values by the equal symbal (=). An example of this would be:

MyVariableOne=ValueOne&MyVariableTwo=ValueTwo

Comment: Makes sense.  And I found queryString.strigify() and queryString.parse() to encode and decode.

Comment: If this data is being sent to the server to be stored, then a GET would not be appropriate - it should be a PUT or POST.

Comment: Yesl the browser initiates  a GET/ the client makes changes which are posted via PUT